# Android layout different on hdpi and xhdpi screen

Tags: android, layout

I have an android xml file where I have used `match_parent`, `wrap_content` and dp units to define views.

But still my layout is rendered differently in different android devices (hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi)
I don't understand why it's happening.

Can anyone help me? I am adding the screenshot for both hdpi and xhdpi phone.
Please let me know how to solve this issue.
[image: Xperia_hpdi]
[image: Motog_xhdpi]
I am also adding my layout file here.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/llshopthat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="348dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gridimage"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBrand"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="25dp"
        android:text="@string/brand"
        android:textColor="#2B1C21"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvBrand"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/clothdesc"
        android:textColor="#757A7C"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDesc"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="25dp"
        android:text="@string/price"
        android:textColor="#2B1C21"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bshop"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#5ACEDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/bShop"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

P.S I didn't want to add Scrollview, but thought may be if nothing worked, this can help the user to see the bottom button. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Your images are not loading.

Comment: Have you made Layout files for hdpi,ldpi and xdpi... , If not then check out [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) for **Supporting Different Screen Sizes** and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for **Supporting Multiple Screens** .

Comment: i see that both images are good, unless i am missing something, anyways, if you did not add XML file for each screen res, then the OS will try to recalculate and place the layout based on the screen res. so OS stretches some images and controls to fit in the screen if no specific XML file is exist for that screen size/res

Comment: Either you'll have to resize the content, or make it scrollable. You can exclude the bottom button from scroller to make it always stay at bottom, while scroller takes rest of the space.

Comment: `Suhi` seems to be **scaled up**, so you are using images which fit good for `Besiva`, but not in both resolutions. If you want to save on images, you should provide the **higher resolution** ones, and let them **scale down** on the missing (lower) resolution folders

Comment: The problem I am mentioning here is that shop button is getting cropped in the hdpi phone,while it gets displayed in xhdpi phone.And, also I don't understand why I should make another layout file for hdpi.
Both hdpi and xhdpi come under normal screen,if I am not wrong. 
Please help in correcting this issue.